# energy of the system increasing after acceleration (one reference frame)

Tags: reference-frames, conservation-laws, relative-motion

The system consists of small mass $m$, large mass $M$, and chemical potential energy $E_{chem}$, as shown in below image, the reference frame is following the small mass throughout.
[image]
The total energy of the system is:

$$ΣE=(m+M)\times{c^2}+E_{chem}$$

The small mass uses the chemical potential energy to accelerate, reaching a velocity of $v$ where $v$ is calculated as such:
$$v=\sqrt{\frac{2\times{E_{chem}}}{m}}$$

[image]

After acceleration, the larger mass will appear to be moving and thus have a kinetic energy: $$E_{K_M}=\frac{M\times{v^2}}{2}$$

This makes a new total energy of:
$$ΣE=(m+M)\times{c^2}+\frac{M\times{v^2}}{2}$$
Consequently the energy change from before to after the acceleration is:
$$ΔΣE=E_{chem}-\frac{M\times{v^2}}{2}$$

Since when $E_{chem}$ and $m$ are constant, $v$ will also be constant, meaning that $M$ can take on any value, and make the net energy change non-zero. Which of the many physical laws that was ignored would come to rescue?

Comment: You've changed your frame of reference! Energy is only conserved for a particular inertial frame. What you have overlooked is relativity.

Comment: Sorry, would you please elaborate this as a formal answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say the small mass will have a certain velocity, *v*, after converting the chemical energy - what frame of reference is that in?  Not in this a frame of reference following the small mass because in that frame of reference the small mass's velocity must always be zero.  For that step you're using what I'll call the page frame of reference - presumably and inertial frame.  If you then switch to considering things from a frame of reference fixed on the small mass you've switched to an accelerating, non-inertial, frame of reference.  That's what's messing up your conservation of energy.

Comment: Could you please explain what will happen when there is really only one reference frame?

Comment: Well, if you consider it from the frame of reference in which the two masses start at rest then you end up with the small mass moving at speed v and the big mass stays at rest.

Comment: The new frame he considers is moving at a constant velocity and thus is inertial. But it's a different inertial frame and so kinetic energy is not necessarily conserved.

Comment: He starts by saying "the reference frame is following the small mass throughout" and then says "The small mass uses the chemical potential energy to accelerate".  Sounds like an accelerating frame of reference to me.

Comment: The *reason* for the difference in energy is not because at some point in time the frame accelerated. When the comparison is made neither frame was accelerating and so both were inertial. My point is that your answer doesn't actually address the underlying physics. True accelerating frames can make physics rather cumbersome and should if at all possible be avoided, however that is not the explanation of this apparent violation of conservation of energy. 
"After acceleration, the larger mass will appear to be moving" 
This is where the dirty work is done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the question: what do we *mean* by "kinetic energy"? I assert that we mean "the amount of energy or 'work' I would need to make this object come to rest in *my frame of reference*".

Consider a ball with mass $m$ in free space 
$${\huge\circ}$$
In it's inertial frame of reference it's velocity is zero so its kinetic energy is also zero. But all inertial frames are equivalent, or at least I cannot say that one is more correct than another so let's consider one which is moving at a velocity $v$ relative to the ball. In this frame the ball *is moving* and has kinetic energy $E_k = mv^2$.
$${\huge\circ} \\ \rightarrow v$$
Thus kinetic energy is a *relative* quantity that depends on your frame of reference.